# Convergence in Distribution and Order Statistics

Tags: order-statistics

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be iid from Exp$(\theta)$ with density function $f(x) = \frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$. Find the limiting distribution of $M_n = Y_1 - \theta\ln(n)$ and $T_n = nY_n$, where $Y_1$ and $Y_n$ represent the first and last order statistics (among $n$ observations) respectively.

**Answer**: The CDF of $X$ is:
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_X(x) & = & P(X\leq x) \\
& = & \int\limits_0^x \frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{t}{\theta}} dt \\
& = & \frac{1}{\theta}\cdot\frac{-\theta}{1}e^{-\frac{t}{\theta}}\Big|_0^x \\
& = & 1 - e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

or $P(X \geq x) = e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}.$ Then since $Y_1 = \min\{X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots, X_n\}$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(Y_1 \geq x) & = & P(\min\{X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots, X_n\} \geq x) \\
& = & P(X_1 \geq x, \ldots, X_n\geq x) \\
& = & P(X_1\geq x)\cdot P(X_n\geq x) \\
& = & (e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}})^n \\
& = & e^{-\frac{xn}{\theta}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

So the CDF of $Y_1$ is:
$$F_{Y_1}(x) = P(Y_1 \leq x) = 1 - e^{-\frac{xn}{\theta}}$$

Thus, the CDF of $M_n$ is:
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{M_n}(x) & = & P(M_n\leq x) \\
& = & P(Y_1 - \theta\ln(n) \leq x) \\
& = & P(Y_1 \leq x + \theta\ln(x)) \\
& =  & 1 - e^{-\frac{n}{\theta}(x + \theta\ln(n)}. 
\end{eqnarray*}

I do not know how to compute the limiting distribution because I am unsure how to evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} F_{M_n}(x)$. Have I completed the mathematics correctly?

I did not attempt $T_n$ portion yet because I believe $M_n$ part is incorrect.

Comment: You sure about the question?. Cause even $Y_n \to \infty$ almost surely, so $T_n = nY_n$, too. And from your calculations it seems that $Y_1 \to 0$ almost surely, so that $M_n \to -\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: This is how the question was posed. I believe my mathematics is correct. I've been told the limiting distribution for $M_n$ is $e^{-e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}}$, but cannot obtain this result.

Comment: Textbooks are not without mistakes. Are you sure that it is not $M_n = Y_n - \theta \log(n)$ and $T_n = n Y_1$ ?

Comment: Again, this is how the question was posed. Perhaps it was a mistake? If what you say is true, how will things change?